# Isaac ROS Nvblox Costmap Plugin For Nav2 Implementation Problems

Tags: navigation, ros2, vslam, nvidia, nav2

I'm trying to use the [Isaac Ros Nvblox](https://github.com/NVIDIA-ISAAC-ROS/isaac_ros_nvblox/tree/2c1654620fa358de74e47ed2919ff8fdc4ad51c8) package with a Realsense D455 depth camera to create a costmap for Nav2. Everything on the Nvblox side works, but I'm a little confused on how to use [their plugin](https://github.com/NVIDIA-ISAAC-ROS/isaac_ros_nvblox/tree/2c1654620fa358de74e47ed2919ff8fdc4ad51c8/nvblox_nav2) with slam_toolbox. On top of that, when I add my own params file to my slam_toolbox command it doesn't look like it's doing anything. Even when I comment it all out, it runs normal.

I added this to the basic mapper_params_online_async.yaml following the [Nav2 documentation](https://navigation.ros.org/plugin_tutorials/docs/writing_new_costmap2d_plugin.html#enable-the-plugin-in-costmap2d). Is that how you would implement their plugin?

```
plugins: ["isaacros"]

isaacros:
  plugin: nvblox_nav2/nvblox_costmap_layer
  enabled: True
```

I'm running slam_toolbox with this command

```
ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_async_launch.py slam_params_file:=/workspaces/isaac_ros-dev/params/mapper_params_online_async.yaml
```

Running 'pwd' in the params folder brings

```
/workspaces/isaac_ros-dev/params
```

I'm running this on a Jetson Orin Nano in the Nvidia Humble docker container

Currently the output in Rviz looks like this when I'm not running the Nvblox node. When I do run the realsense example the Nvblox node no longer works while I run the slam_toolbox.

[image: Rviz slam toolbox output]

But I should be seeing the 3D view of Nvblox with the their costmap below. The [Nvblox docs](https://nvblox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/examples/ros_example.html) show a view like this, which is my goal.

[image]

When this is talked about online, it's always in the context of using the IsaacSim simulator. The only thing I've seen of this being implemented on real hardware is in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EDQiwWbjnws&pp=ygUWdGlua2VyIHR3aW5zIGlzYWFjIHJvcw%3D%3D) video from Tinker Twins.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm pretty new to the Nav2 stack:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this particular package but my guess is that you're just not adding the meshes to rviz to be viewable https://github.com/NVIDIA-ISAAC-ROS/isaac_ros_nvblox/blob/2c1654620fa358de74e47ed2919ff8fdc4ad51c8/nvblox_ros/src/lib/nvblox_node.cpp#L244-L254

I'm not sure what the comment on SLAM Toolbox is about - since the global costmap for planning and mapping for localization are separate concepts.